# AppEngine: "Call error 3: invalid security ticket" when using memcache

Tags: google-app-engine, go, memcached

I only recently noticed it happening more frequently after I implemented session management on top of datastore and memcache, but, now, as I actually explicitly push data into memcache, it is now happening constantly. Most often, I'll get this error every time until I flush, it will work once, and then I'll get this error every time afterward.

The requests that are inciting the issue are very simple (try *get* from memcache, do *get* from datastore, *put* to memcache), so they're very quick. The request either completes or fails within a second. Any ideas?

```
<-- Current user reconcile here.
2016/09/01 03:00:42 DEBUG: Session save not necessary: [DCRBDGRY6RMWANCSJXVLD7GULDH4NZEB6SBAQ3KSFIGA2LP45IIQ]    
2016/09/01 03:00:42 DEBUG: Got session: [DCRBDGRY6RMWANCSJXVLD7GULDH4NZEB6SBAQ3KSFIGA2LP45IIQ]
2016/09/01 03:00:42 DEBUG: Found user in session.
<-- Request-specific handler logic here.
2016/09/01 03:00:42 DEBUG: Cache hit: [type.family:522450f6795592f844a27213a2dddf8de169f204]
2016/09/01 03:00:42 ERROR: context expired before API call datastore_v3/Put completed
request URL: /api/1/type/family/522450f6795592f844a27213a2dddf8de169f204
panic: Call error 3: invalid security ticket (context expired)
```

Maybe if I could understand the nature of the failure and how it might potentially be tricked to fire so early I might be more helpful in providing more information?

Comment: The context that you're passing to the datastore is expiring too quickly or being cancelled by an upstream request before the datastore can persist the data

Comment: This implies that the Memcache call itself is canceling the request since this only happens when I access Memcache. Is a fault potentially destabilizing the request?

Comment: It's unlikely a memcache call can cancel a request, usually the other way around. A request has a context, which is passed to memcache/datastore. The context has a done channel which is listened to by memcache/datastore. If the done channel gets closed, memcache/datastore will stop doing whatever they were doing

Comment: Yes.. I'm just having trouble thinking of how that can happen. I'm guessing that it's my assumptions. Looking at the memcache logic, at the AppEngine level, it's not touching anything inside he context so it's not inadvertently interfering. Can I assume that datastore workflow is sufficiently done by the time the Put() returns?

Comment: I see you've already seen [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/Kb5iYjhfang)

Comment: Yeah :) . If my post has been approved then it has gathered little interest.

Comment: It looks like, when I'm not using Memcache, I can rapidly, repeatedly call the API request, but, if I'm using Memcache, I can't call more than once or twice, even waiting for ten-seconds in-between. Let me know if you have any insight, here. The payloads are only about five-hundred bytes.

Comment: Nope sorry all you

Comment: By the way.. It turns out that I had a lingering goroutine buried in the lower-level logic. Every so often it'd try to write to datastore after the request had already ended. It seems to only have happened when I used Memcache.